# How can i reduce uploaded image size without losing quality(much)

Tags: php, image, optimization

I have image folder which contains almost 150000 images and the images are not compressed. So i want to compress the image without changing anything because our site is live.

I have tired `ShortPixel an image compressor` but it did not work for me

can you please suggest me some api or tools to optimize my server images. images are majorly in JPG, JPEG and PNG formate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this repository, I think it’s great with custom configuration like how much quality you want to retain.
https://github.com/spatie/image-optimizer
Edit: Or if you want to make it simple, you can use this paid api: https://kraken.io/

Comment: Thanks @owenizedd for your reply. Actually I want to retain minimum 75% quality of images. Will it worke?.

Comment: Yes there’s config there, you can set any percentage you want

Comment: can you suggest any free or paid api in which i just pass the image path and rest will done by the api? @owenizedd

Comment: Yes, here it is https://kraken.io/

Comment: any other please becoz kraken.in not replying. @owenizedd

Comment: https://tinypng.com/developers try tinypng